# How do I make my divs line up, despite different text lengths?

Tags: html, list, text, character, pad

**EDITED**

Here's my updated question:   I've included a link to my site which shows the exact problem [here](http://testsite24.netai.net/public/public.html) The first box has a title that is short, and therefore doesn't push the the two divs beneath it (location and price) down very far. The second box has a slightly longer title, so it pushes slightly more. The third box has the longest title and pushes more than box 1 and 2.

In this instance, I'd want box #1 and #2 to have "blank space" padded onto their title divs in order to push the location/price divs down lower (like in box #3). This needs to be dynamic, because sometimes box #1 will have the longest title. I thought blank characters might work but apparently not...

Thanks for any help!

**BELOW THIS LINE IS OLD**
My site has a list item which contains an image, and 3 divs (titlebox,locationbox, and pricebox).

The line I'm interested in is titlebox, mainly I'd like like it to *always* have 40 characters in it. If there's less, I need blank padding added.

I'll post the entire list code below, but here is just the title div:

```
<div class="titlebox">Exceptional House with a View</div>
```

This title only has 29 characters, but I want it to be treated as if it has 40. I don't care if there's more than 40, 
I only need a function **to pad the text with blank space until 40 characters**.

How is this possible? Thank you!

Here is the entire list item:

```
<li class="list__item">
            <figure class="list__item__inner">
            <a class="divLink" href="http://www.testsite.com/BEE/info.html">
             <p class="vignette" style="background-image:url(http://www.fakesite.com/image2.jpg)"></p>
             <div class="titlebox">Exceptional House with a View</div>
       <div class="locationbox">BorrisVille</div>
     <div class="pricebox">Asking $349,000</div>
     </a>
</li>
```

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: You could use min-width=...

Comment: You're probably looking for the CSS setting min-width.  Otherwise we get into messy things like "40 characters in which font at which size?"

Comment: You cannot do that in CSS. In fact, CSS has no functions, really. It is difficult to see why you would want to pad to a specific width in characters, since the widths of characters vary. Consider reconsidering what you really wish to achieve and formulate the question differently. Perhaps you wish to set a minimum width for an element. But which width? A character is not a suitable measure, unless you are using a monospace font.

Comment: I've updated my original question, please read! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considering using the CSS min-width?

`<div style="min-width: 200px;"></div>`

To answer your question, you could also make a method in Javascript/jQuery, but this looks/feels sloppy:

```
function maxOut() {
        var spacesNeeded = 40 - $('#myDiv').html().length;
        var spacer = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < spacesNeeded; i++) {
            spacer += '&nbsp;';
        }
        $('#myDiv').append(spacer);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I placed it within script tags within my html and no change. Besides, this method would only act like blank space (which I asked) but this causes the real text to be affected, ie pushed over and squished. I don't want that. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Nova - Well, I don't really recommend using that method. Perhaps you could post a jsfiddle  (jsfiddle.com) of the current issue and someone here can help adjust to what you're looking for?